# How to implement AdMob in Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, admob

I have a phonegap application and im trying to implementing Admob.

I'm using phonegap version 1.4.1 and I am using this site as my reference : http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/iphonedev/implementing-admob-ads-in-a-phonegap-project-for-ios-no-plugins-required/

My code is as follows:

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{

bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]init];
[bannerView_ setDelegate:self];
[bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.viewController.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

// only valid if AdGap.plist specifies a protocol to handle
if(self.invokeString)
{
    // this is passed before the deviceready event is fired, so you can access it in js when you receive deviceready
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var invokeString = \"%@\";", self.invokeString];
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}
```

Everything is fine, but when I am running the application, no ads are being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your "theWebView" object finishes its webload. And that the bannerView_ is a registered property of your object.

Also, I hope you just put in "MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID" to hide your banner unit id.

Check up with your admob settings if the banner unit id is correct.

And finally, please use a iphone proxy like Charles or similar to validate that the call goes out as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap has been upgraded. It support new features. just add this code in your config.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="1.0.0" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
```